# hide/show different content in todo list and show one content at a time using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, vue.js

I am building this web using the laravel framework and I am not good at js tricks as I need to list todo titles only but when the user clicks on them it shows its own content. so far it only works for the last one.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
                    <h1>Painted List <a href="/create" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h1>
                    <ul>
                    @if(count($paints) > 0)
                    @foreach($paints as $paint)
                            <li onclick="myFunction()"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> {{ $paint->title }}</li>
                            <div class="card-body" id="contentBody">
                                <p class="content"> {{$paint->content}} </p>
                            </div>
                            <script>
                            function myFunction() {
                            var x = document.getElementById("contentBody");
                            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                                x.style.display = "block";
                            } else {
                                x.style.display = "none";
                            }
                            }
                            </script>
                    @endforeach
                    @else
                    <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> No Paint yet!</li>
                    @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

that is my code I hope someone gonna helps me to show and hide using CSS, javascript, and HTML

As one helped and now it shows content when clicked but not one content at a time [In this photo shows that I have clicked in both headers and all content from two headers are shown ut that is not what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5rRu.png)

Comment: I don't know how laravel works, but I can definitely tell that `<script>` tag should not be inside a `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put onclick in div inside <li> to allow return to parent <li> and put card-body element inside <li> and use <script> outside foreach to avoid repetition.
Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>Painted List <a href="/create" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h1>
<ul>
    @if(count($paints) > 0)
    @foreach($paints as $paint)
    <li>
        <div onclick="myFunction(this)"><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> {{ $paint->title }}</div>
        <div class="card-body" id="contentBody">
            <p class="content"> {{$paint->content}} </p>
        </div>
    </li>
    @endforeach
        <script>
            function myFunction(el) {
                var p = el.parentNode; // return from div you clicked it to <li>
                var x = p.querySelector('.card-body');  // find card-body
                //var x = document.getElementById("contentBody");
                if (x.style.display === "none") {
                    x.style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    x.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
    @else
    <li><span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span> No Paint yet!</li>
    @endif
</ul>
```

The best and simple way is to use JQuery it takes few lines and does the job because the Laravel hates in-scripts as it is very sensitive in security.

```
$('.non').on('click', function(e){
   if (e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display === "none") {
     $('.contentBody').hide()
    e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
} else {
  e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
}
 })
```

friend of mine came over and bang saw my sad face then miracles happen that only Js clipless understands

Comment: It now shows different contents but it has a new problem what I also need it should display one content at a time

Comment: i don't understand your problem